# Why my Chrome Extensions directory is empty in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Why my C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions directory is empty?

[image]

Even though I have several extensions installed[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `chrome://version/` and look at the `Profile Path` property. This will be where Chrome saves your local data (cache, bookmarks, extensions etc..)

[image]

I would hazard a guess that your `Profile Path` isn't the folder you're looking in.